# Get Selected Item on Column on Datagrid WPF and Find it by Linq

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, linq, datagrid

Hello i am using wpf datagrid. I have **dataGrid_Division** contains 3 columns **D_ID** , **D_Name** and **Branch_ID** .

there is also another datagrid **dataGrid_Branch** contains 2 **column B_ID** and **B_Name**
i want to get what user select record in **dataGrid_Branch** it store the **B_ID** and Look for all results with the same id on my database **Division.B_ID** its just a one to many relation.

then i want all results displayed on **dataGrid_Division** with all records that have the same id of **B_ID**.
so to sum up `Select * from Division where ID = ID` of selected row on the **dataGrid.Branch** and sorry i am not good in english.

```
private void Departments_page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _dbObj = new medical_databaseEntitiescon();
            dataGrid_Branch.ItemsSource = _dbObj.branches.ToList();
        }

        private void dataGrid_Branch_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            _dbObj = new medical_databaseEntitiescon();

           // I want to Do the action here

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should look something like this:

```
var selectedBranch = dataGrid_Branch.SelectedItem as Branch;
var selectedDivisions = _dbObj.divisions.Where(x => x.B_ID == selectedBranch.B_ID).ToList();

dataGrid_Division.ItemsSource = selectedDivisions;
```

You didn't mention the name of your divisions structure so I assumed it to be `divisions`.

Comment: the only error i got is the as Branch any ideas ? is Branch a variable or my data table ?

Comment: any one can explain the **as Branch;** part guys ?

Comment: It is the type of your _dbObj.branches -structure. Just change it to the correct data type. I just assumed it to be Branch as you mentioned.